# Why does TypeScript allow overriding a method with a subclass parameter?

Tags: typescript

I was surprised to learn that TypeScript allows a subclass to specify a more narrow type in a parameter list when overriding a method. I have to imagine this is not an oversight, but an intentional choice by the TypeScript team. But why? What benefit does it give to allow this pattern?

For example:

```
interface Vehicle {
  model: string;
}

interface TowTruck extends Vehicle {
  towing: Vehicle;
}

class VehicleHelper {
  stringify(vehicle: Vehicle) {
    return vehicle.model;
  }
}

class TowTruckHelper extends VehicleHelper {
  // override parameter to be more specific than "Vehicle"
  stringify(towTruck: TowTruck) {
    return (
      super.stringify(towTruck)
      + ' towing a '
      + super.stringify(towTruck.towing)
    );
  }
}

const myHelper: VehicleHelper = new TowTruckHelper();
console.log(myHelper.stringify({ model: 'Camry' }));
```

There is no TypeScript error reported, but running it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is by design. Class methods relate bivariantly. Initially all functions related bivariantly but [`strictFunctionTypes`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654) tighten this up for function signatures that do not originate in method definitions:

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those originating in method or constructor declarations. Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as Array) continue to mostly relate covariantly. The impact of strictly checking methods would be a much bigger breaking change as a large number of generic types would become invariant (even so, we may continue to explore this stricter mode).

And indeed if you use a function field instead of a method, under strictFunctionTypes you get an error:

```
interface Vehicle {
    model: string;
}

interface TowTruck extends Vehicle {
    towing: Vehicle;
}

class VehicleHelper {
    stringify = function (vehicle: Vehicle) {
        return vehicle.model;
    }
}

class TowTruckHelper extends VehicleHelper {
    // Property 'stringify' in type 'TowTruckHelper' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'VehicleHelper'.
    stringify = function (this: TowTruckHelper, towTruck: TowTruck) {
        return (
            VehicleHelper.prototype.stringify.apply(this, towTruck)
            + ' towing a '
            + VehicleHelper.prototype.stringify.apply(this, towTruck.towing)
        );
    }
}

const myHelper: VehicleHelper = new TowTruckHelper();
console.log(myHelper.stringify({ model: 'Camry' }));
```

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22156) is also a related issue with the exact behavior you describe marked working as intended.

Comment: I don't yet understand all the terminology used here, but this is clearly exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @EricSimonton sorry for the jargon overload, I guess I spent too much time around the compiler github page :P. Let me know if you need any clarifications.