# Unexpected behavior when implements interface with argument overloading

Tags: typescript

I meet a case when TypeScript allows to call method with wrong type of an argument. Why TypeScript compiler does not handle this as problem?

```js
interface IValue {
    add(value: IValue): IValue;
}

class NumberValue implements IValue {
    private readonly _rawNumber: number;

    public constructor(rawValue: number) {
        this._rawNumber = rawValue;
    }

    public add(value: NumberValue): NumberValue {
        const sum: number = this._rawNumber + value._rawNumber;
        return new NumberValue(sum);
    }
}

class StringValue implements IValue {
    private readonly _rawString: string;

    public constructor(rawValue: string) {
        this._rawString = rawValue;
    }

    public add(value: StringValue): StringValue {
        const sum: number = Number.parseFloat(this._rawString) + Number.parseFloat(value._rawString);
        return new StringValue(sum.toFixed());
    }
}

const v1: IValue = new NumberValue(42);
const v2: IValue = new StringValue("42");

// Unexpected behavior: No any errors/warnings. The method NumberValue#add() called with argument of StringValue type
const v3: IValue = v1.add(v2);
```

My tsconfig.json is

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true
    }
}
```

I expect to receive compilation error, but no any errors/warnings

Comment: Well, v1's declared type is IValue. IValue.add() expects an IValue as argument. And v2 is an IValue, so I'm not surprised that this line compiles fine. What is more surprising is that NumberValue and StringValue compile, since they override add() but don't respect its contract by accepting only NumberValue or StringValue, instead of accepting any IValue as the base method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460342/why-does-typescript-allow-overriding-a-method-with-a-subclass-parameter for why NumberValue and StringValue compile.

Comment: Yes, I means same surprising. For me, we can safely change type of return value (according inheritance), but change type of arguments broke contact of interface...
Thanks for point...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make an interface using the [polymorphic this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types)

```
interface IValue {
    add(value: this): this;
}
```

Comment: My idea is to make instances of implementation classes as immutable objects. Polymorphic this is good for [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). If I will use Polymorphic this, the user will expect that my object is not immutable.

Comment: Nevermind, I might have just realized your issue. You are wrongly typing v1 and v2 as `IValue` and not their actual type. That's why Typescript isn't throwing. v1 is expecting another `IValue` argument passed to the `add` method, and that's exactly what you are providing.