# Why can a derived class override a method with a subtype parameter?

Tags: typescript

It seems that in TypeScript, when extending a class, my subclass can override a method with a parameter type which is the subtype of its base class:

```js
abstract class Base {
  abstract greet(name: "Alice" | "Bob"): void;
}

class Derived extends Base {
  override greet(name: "Alice"): void { // <=== WHY NO ERROR?
    // Do something, assuming that name === "Alice"...
  }
}
```

This is allowed, but it apparently violates the OO principle. For example, I can easily create some unsafe code like this:

```js
function createObject(): Base {
  return new Derived();
}

function unsafeGreet(): void {
  const obj = createObject();
  obj.greet("Bob");
}

unsafeGreet();
```

I would like to know:

- Why is this allowed in TypeScript? What is the reason behind this design?
- How to properly write OO code in TypeScript to work around this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does TypeScript allow overriding a method with a subclass parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460342/why-does-typescript-allow-overriding-a-method-with-a-subclass-parameter)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, thank you for the link! But I still wonder if there is a way to enforce strict type checking for method types. Or we have to live with this design and be more careful by ourselves? Thanks again!